# How can I print a fileset to a file, one file name per line?

Tags: ant, fileset

I have a populated fileset and I need to print the matching filenames into a text file.

I tried this:

```
<fileset id="myfileset" dir="../sounds">
    <include name="*.wav" />
    <include name="*.ogg" />
</fileset>

<property name="sounds" refid="myfileset" />
<echo file="sounds.txt">${sounds}</echo>
```

which prints all the files on a single line, separated by semicolons. I need to have one file per line. How can I do this without resorting to calling OS commands or writing Java code?

**UPDATE**:

Ah, should have been more specific - the list must not contain directories. I'm marking ChssPly76's as the accepted answer anyway, since the [pathconvert](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pathconvert.html) command was exactly what I was missing. To strip the directories and list only the filenames, I used the ["flatten" mapper](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html#flatten-mapper).

Here is the script that I ended up with:

```
<fileset id="sounds_fileset" dir="../sound">
    <include name="*.wav" />
    <include name="*.ogg" />
</fileset>

<pathconvert pathsep="&#xA;" property="sounds" refid="sounds_fileset">
    <mapper type="flatten" />
</pathconvert>

<echo file="sounds.txt">${sounds}</echo>
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Use the [PathConvert](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pathconvert.html) task:

```
<fileset id="myfileset" dir="../sounds">
    <include name="*.wav" />
    <include name="*.ogg" />
</fileset>

<pathconvert pathsep="${line.separator}" property="sounds" refid="myfileset">
    <!-- Add this if you want the path stripped -->
    <mapper>
        <flattenmapper />
    </mapper>
</pathconvert>
<echo file="sounds.txt">${sounds}</echo>
```

Comment: The Pathconvert task seems to create the absolute file path. Is there a possibility to prevent this? I have the same issue and want to print a list of files but not the full path but a relative path (so flatten won't work for me)

Comment: @Soccertrash, I solved this with post-processing the file with `<replace file="${sounds.txt}" token="${basedir}\" value="" />` to remove the common base dir prefix (in my case).

Comment: @mgaert, you can do it in-place as `<map from="${basedir} to=""/>`. Place it within `<pathconvert>`.

Answer (score 4):

Since Ant 1.6 you can use [toString](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#pathshortcut):

```
<echo file="sounds.txt">${toString:myfileset}</echo>
```