# How can I echo a filename twice using 'FileSet' and 'PathConvert'?

Tags: ant, fileset

I have this simple Ant task that lists all '.png' files in a folder:

```
<target name="listimages">
    <!-- Assume files a A and B -->
    <fileset id="dist.contents" dir="${basedir}">
        <include name="**/*.png"/>
    </fileset>

    <pathconvert pathsep="${line.separator}"
                 property="prop.dist.contents" 
                 refid="dist.contents">
        <mapper type="flatten" />
        <map from="${basedir}" to=""/>
    </pathconvert>
    <echo>${prop.dist.contents}</echo>
</target>
```

This prints

```
[echo] A.png
[echo] B.png
```

But, what I want is for the filenames to appear *twice* on each line.

```
[echo] A.png,A.png
[echo] B.png,B.png
```

How can I do that?

(This question is a follow up to [How can I print a fileset to a file, one file name per line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456852/ant-commands-to-print-fileset-into-a-file-one-match-per-line))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [regexp mapper](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html) (instead of the flatten) that implements the flattening and duplication.  This is pretty simplistic, but might do:

```
<mapper type="regexp" from=".*/(.*)" to="\1,\1" />
```

Would need adjusting for your local path separator.

Better though, use a chainedmapper in place of the flatten:

```
<chainedmapper>
    <mapper type="flatten" />
    <mapper type="regexp" from="(.*)" to="\1,\1" />
</chainedmapper>
```